# Does a car lease count as a car loan for credit reporting purposes?

Tags: credit-score, auto-leasing

I've been told that I need to get a loan on my credit report to increase my credit score. I've never gotten any type of loan before.

If I get a car lease, does that count as a loan for increasing my credit score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, a lease affects your credit score in a similar manner as a loan.

In fact, a lease often requires slightly better credit in order to get the best terms, compared to a loan.

Alternative answer to your question: [research proven ways to improve your credit score](http://www.experian.com/credit-education/improve-credit-score.html). A car loan may not be the answer.

Sources:

[Does Leasing a Vehicle Affect the Credit Score the Same as Purchasing a Car?](http://classroom.synonym.com/leasing-vehicle-affect-credit-score-same-purchasing-car-18708.html)

[How Leasing Versus Buying a Car Impacts on Your Credit](http://www.straightcreditcounseling.com/credit_articles_leasing_vs_buying_car.asp)

[Three Things You Must Do Before Leasing a Car](http://blog.credit.com/2014/03/3-things-you-must-do-before-you-lease-a-car-78266/)

Comment: Alternative alternative answer: if you aren't using credit stupidly or otherwise creating problems, credit rating will take care of itself.